# How to trigger document.ready event affter angular component finish render

Tags: angular, events, triggers, document-ready

I need to trigger document.ready event from angular, inside of component. I need this, because external firefox/chrome extension only run when document ready event is fired.

More detail. Inside of my component I add element meta tag to the head of page. And I have a firefox/chrome extension that read this meta only when document.redy event is fired

Comment: `ngAfterViewInit` is a good candidate for this use case.

Comment: I guess you have to render it on server side.

Comment: ok, ngAfterViewInit is exected when component is rendered but my question is how to fire document.ready event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to trigger an event.

```
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('ZoteroItemUpdated', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true
        }));
```

Now the Zotero pluggin refresh when I update the meta tags in head of the page